# Paint is flaking off

Tags: word-choice, phrasal-verbs, present-continuous

[image]

I saw the verbs flake off and peel is used for these situations but I would like to ask how to inform a painter or someone about the problem in different and unambiguous ways.

For example, which one is better?

> The ceiling is flaking off / peeling.

or

> The paint on the ceiling is flaking off/ peeling.

And can I use "pull down" and "fall off/down" such as

> The paint on the wall pulls down.
>
> The paint on the ceiling falls down/ falls off.

Comment: Forget pull down and fall off. Things or people fall off places. Only a can of paint can fall off a table, for example.

Comment: What's in your image looks like wallpaper, not paint.

Comment: @Lambie Not really, except they both can "peel". Wallpaper doesn't really flake, but it can rip. And paint doesn't rip.

Comment: @Laurel That is simply not true. Wallpaper can peel away from  or off  the wall and peel off the wall, just like paint. See for yourself: https://www.facebook.com/theguardian/posts/the-wallpaper-was-peeling-off-the-walls-the-carpet-was-thin-dirty-and-stained-th/10152858804756323/

Comment: And flake off: https://www.google.com/search?biw=1191&bih=706&ei=Gp7AW46KDMG7ggeT6ZqIDA&q=%22wallpaper+was+flaking++off%22&oq=%22wallpaper+was+flaking++off%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...3447.4853..5244...0.0..0.106.689.8j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......33i299.PwNtk5f4e-c

Answer (score 1):

The phrasal verbs are "flake off" and "peel off".  "Flack off" is incorrect.

The original post's illustration shows "peeling" paint.  "Flakes" are much smaller.  "Peeling" implies that the pieces are long enough that you can pull on them to remove more material.

Comment: flaking off and peeling is right. The paint is peeling. No need for off, but it isn't wrong.